# pdflatex hangs during compiling (every 2nd run)

Tags: errors, pdftex, compiling

Newly, it frequently happens that `pdflatex` hangs during compile.

The system:

- TeXLive 2010
  (yes, I know that 2011 is out already)
- MacOS X 10.6.8.
- Texstudio as editor

Currently, I'm compiling in the command line by

```
  pdflatex -synctex=1  filename.tex
```

Often, but not always (!) it then happens that `pdflatex` stops e. g. at the following line, the cpu usage of the process `pdftex` increases dramatically and it does not proceed compiling until I stop it with Ctrl-C, x and Return.

```
  LaTeX Warning: Reference `nameofreference' on page 49 undefined on input line 1179.
```

If I compile again, mostly it works and the pdf is created completely...
(And as I tried it some minutes ago, the 3rd try again stopped at the same line...,
the 4th try worked, the 5th stopped.
It seems to happen alternately - every second pdflatex run hangs at this line...)

- How is that possible
- and what can I do to avoid this incomplete processing?

Comment: Don't know if this will really help you, but what if you (everytime you stop editing and want to compile) delete all the `.aux` files, and then run twice or three times `pdflatex`?

Comment: I suspect an error that triggers infinite recursion. It's impossible to say more without an example.

Comment: @Nicolás: as my file is quite large (and already takes a considerable time to compile once), this would be quite time-consuming and normally should be not necessary to remove the aux files each time, no?

Comment: @egreg thanks! I do not know how to produce a MWE in this case - the file is the working copy of my complete dissertation and I don't want to upload or "publish" it anywhere. :-| Do you think I should be able to reduce the problem to one paragraph or line of code - maybe the one where it hangs?

Comment: Make a copy of the file, and then start stripping the copy apart, compiling regularly. This should lead you to get a MWE that demonstrates the problem, which could be content related, or perhaps a package conflict. It might even help you solve the problem :)

Comment: Do you use packages afterpage and longtable maybe a longtable at `\afterpage` or simply a longtable near `\afterpage`? If so, that is a known issue.

Comment: @Schweinebacke: thanks! I do use many longtables, but I don't use teh `afterpage` package (only `flafter`).  (BTW: nice nickname ;-) )

Comment: @Martin: flafter does not work like afterpage and I cannot find any issue about using longtable together with flafter. But flafter modifies `\@addtocurcol` and thats a piece of the LaTeX output routine. longtable modifies output too, so maybe, maybe, maybe collision of both may be a similar problem like collision of afterpage and longtable. Perhaps a `\FloatBarrier` (package placeins) before each longtable may help.

Comment: The fact that it works every other time makes me think that something in the aux file is the causing the problem.  When it doesn't work, it probably writes a blank aux file so next time it does work, but then the aux file has the problematic line so next time it doesn't work.  Could you post your aux file?  (If it's not too long)

Comment: http://ctan.org/pkg/thumbs 2011/05/14 v1.0a had a bug, fixed in 2011/05/18 v1.0b: "Bug fix: When a document using the thumbs package was compiled, and the .aux and .tmb files were created, and the .tmb file was deleted (or renamed or moved), while the .aux file was not deleted (or renamed or moved), and the document was compiled again, and the .aux file was reused, then reading from the then empty .tmb file resulted in an endless loop. Fixed." I do not know whether you use that package and which version of it, of course.

Comment: @AndrewStacey: thanks, I'll try to update my question with the aux file and more details. Another interesting fact: the problem occured when compiling my document with `\include{}` containing only two of the input files. When I removed the included (and compiled the whole document, I could not reproduce the error (but sure, then the reference was not missing any more).